# Adding the same movieclip multiple times to the stage

Tags: actionscript-3

Iam trying to to learn action script 3 with flash cs6 by creating a game, what i want is to place random cards on the stage multiple times so user adds them up and they disappear,
ive got the cards appearing on the stage but getting the multiple versions to appear is where i am stopped, i can only get them to appear once, anybody have an idea how to do this ?
thank you very much

```
stop();

var pressed_1:int =0;

var pressed_2:int =0;





 function checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2)

{
    if (pressed_1+pressed_2 ==11)
    {
    trace("winner");
    trace(pressed_1+pressed_2);
    }
    else
    {
    trace ("loser")
    trace(pressed_1+pressed_2);
    pressed_1=0;
    pressed_2=0;
    trace("is it reset 1 to " +pressed_1);
    trace("is it reset 2 to " +pressed_2);
    trace("this is  1 now " +pressed_1);
    trace("this is  2 now " +pressed_2);
    }

}



 function click_1(Event:MouseEvent = null)
    {
        if (pressed_1==0)
            {
            pressed_1=1;
            trace("holder_1 = " + pressed_1);
            cardPrint1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_1);
            trace("button 1 disabled")
            cardPrint1.alpha =.5;
            }
        else if (pressed_2==0)
            {
            pressed_2=1;
            trace("holder_2 = " + pressed_2);
            cardPrint1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_1);
            trace("button 1 disabled")
            cardPrint1.alpha =.5;
            checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2);

            }
    }

 function click_2(Event:MouseEvent = null)
    {
        if(pressed_1==0)
        {
            pressed_1=2;
            trace("holder_1 = " + pressed_1);
            cardPrint2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_2);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint2.alpha =.5;

        }
        else if (pressed_2==0 )
        {

            pressed_2=2;
            trace("holder_2 = " + pressed_2);
            cardPrint2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_2);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint2.alpha =.5;
            checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2);
        }

    }

 function click_3(Event:MouseEvent = null)
    {
        if(pressed_1==0)
        {
            pressed_1=3;
            trace("holder_1 = " + pressed_1);
            cardPrint3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_3);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint3.alpha =.5;

        }
        else if (pressed_2==0 )
        {

            pressed_2=3;
            trace("holder_2 = " + pressed_2);
            cardPrint3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_3);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint3.alpha =.5;
            checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2);
        }

    }


function click_4(Event:MouseEvent = null)
    {
        if(pressed_1==0)
        {
            pressed_1=4;
            trace("holder_1 = " + pressed_1);
            cardPrint4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_4);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint4.alpha =.5;

        }
        else if (pressed_2==0 )
        {

            pressed_2=4;
            trace("holder_2 = " + pressed_2);
            cardPrint4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_4);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint4.alpha =.5;
            checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2);
        }

    }


 function click_5(Event:MouseEvent = null)
    {
        if(pressed_1==0)
        {
            pressed_1=5;
            trace("holder_1 = " + pressed_1);
            cardPrint5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_5);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint5.alpha =.5;

        }
        else if (pressed_2==0 )
        {

            pressed_2=5;
            trace("holder_2 = " + pressed_2);
            cardPrint5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_5);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint5.alpha =.5;
            checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2);
        }

    }


 function click_6(Event:MouseEvent = null)
    {
        if(pressed_1==0)
        {
            pressed_1=6;
            trace("holder_1 = " + pressed_1);
            cardPrint6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_6);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint6.alpha =.5;

        }
        else if (pressed_2==0 )
        {

            pressed_2=6;
            trace("holder_2 = " + pressed_2);
            cardPrint6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_6);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint6.alpha =.5;
            checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2);
        }

    }


 function click_7(Event:MouseEvent = null)
    {
        if(pressed_1==0)
        {
            pressed_1=7;
            trace("holder_1 = " + pressed_1);
            cardPrint7.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_7);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint7.alpha =.5;

        }
        else if (pressed_2==0 )
        {

            pressed_2=7;
            trace("holder_2 = " + pressed_2);
            cardPrint7.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_7);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint7.alpha =.5;
            checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2);
        }

    }


 function click_8(Event:MouseEvent = null)
    {
        if(pressed_1==0)
        {
            pressed_1=8;
            trace("holder_1 = " + pressed_1);
            cardPrint8.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_8);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint8.alpha =.5;

        }
        else if (pressed_2==0 )
        {

            pressed_2=8;
            trace("holder_2 = " + pressed_2);
            cardPrint8.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_8);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint8.alpha =.5;
            checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2);
        }

    }


 function click_9(Event:MouseEvent = null)
    {
        if(pressed_1==0)
        {
            pressed_1=9;
            trace("holder_1 = " + pressed_1);
            cardPrint9.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_9);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint9.alpha =.5;

        }
        else if (pressed_2==0 )
        {

            pressed_2=9;
            trace("holder_2 = " + pressed_2);
            cardPrint9.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_9);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint9.alpha =.5;
            checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2);
        }

    }


 function click_10(Event:MouseEvent = null)
    {
        if(pressed_1==0)
        {
            pressed_1=10;
            trace("holder_1 = " + pressed_1);
            cardPrint10.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,       click_10);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint10.alpha =.5;

        }
        else if (pressed_2==0 )
        {

            pressed_2=10;
            trace("holder_2 = " + pressed_2);
            cardPrint10.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_10);
            trace("button 2 disabled");
            cardPrint10.alpha =.5;
            checkTol (pressed_1,pressed_2);
        }

    }



var cardPrint1 :MovieClip = new card_1();
this.addChild(cardPrint1);
cardPrint1.x =50;
cardPrint1.y =35;
cardPrint1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_1);


var cardPrint2 :MovieClip = new card_2();
this.addChild(cardPrint2);
cardPrint2.x =100;
cardPrint2.y =35;
cardPrint2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_2);

var cardPrint3 :MovieClip = new card_3();
this.addChild(cardPrint3);
cardPrint3.x =150;
cardPrint3.y =35;
cardPrint3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_3);

var cardPrint4 :MovieClip = new card_4();
this.addChild(cardPrint4);
cardPrint4.x =200;
cardPrint4.y =35;
cardPrint4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_4);

var cardPrint5 :MovieClip = new card_5();
this.addChild(cardPrint5);
cardPrint5.x =250;
cardPrint5.y =35;
cardPrint5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_5);

var cardPrint6 :MovieClip = new card_6();
this.addChild(cardPrint6);
cardPrint6.x =300;
cardPrint6.y =35;
cardPrint6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_6);

var cardPrint7 :MovieClip = new card_7();
this.addChild(cardPrint7);
cardPrint7.x =350;
cardPrint7.y =35;
cardPrint7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_7);

var cardPrint8 :MovieClip = new card_8();
this.addChild(cardPrint8);
cardPrint8.x =400;
cardPrint8.y =35;
cardPrint8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_8);

var cardPrint9 :MovieClip = new card_9();
this.addChild(cardPrint9);
cardPrint9.x =450;
cardPrint9.y =35;
cardPrint9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_9);

var cardPrint10 :MovieClip = new card_10();
this.addChild(cardPrint10);
cardPrint10.x =500;
cardPrint10.y =35;
cardPrint10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_10);
```

Comment: I am going to suggest that you first take some time to learn about arrays, as they could greatly simplify what you are trying to do. http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-arrays/

Answer (score 1):

Create an array loop that adds a new variable movieclip each loop.  Then push it to the array and call to it through a loop as `myarray[i]` `i` represents the numeric integer used in the loop.

ex:

```
var movieclip = new MovieClip;
addChild(movieclip);
array.push(movieclip);
```

Then to call the movieclips:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++)
{
    array[i].dosomething();
}
```